# Apple Numbers using AND in formula to find dupes

Tags: numbers

I don't get it how to use multiple conditions in the following case...

```
IF(COUNTIF(name,name)>1 AND(ISBLANK(meaning)),"x", "")
```

What this should do is compare the cells in column A (name) for duplicates and also check if column G (meaning) is blank. But it tells me syntax error. Where and how do I use the AND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! AND cannot be used since it's a function itself, instead IF needs to be nested, like this...

```
IF(COUNTIF(name,name)>1,IF(ISBLANK(meaning),"X",""),"")
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution! You can mark your own answer as answered so others with the same question can find it.